# ¿Como guardo el texto escrito en la barra de comentarios en html?

Tags: html5

En este código cree una barra de comentarios, pero el problema es que no se como guardar lo escrito.
`<form>
        <textarea name="comentarios" id="comentarios" cols="30" rows="10">
            Introduzca aquí sus comentarios
        </textarea>
    </form>`

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?¿En donde lo quieres guardar?¿Que lenguaje? te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: guardar el texto escrito o obtener ese texto escrito? si quieres guardarlo pues lo mas recomendable es utilizar base de datos, si quieres obtenerlos seria mediante javascript o tambien mediante php. Explica mejor lo que quieres lograr

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que quieres tomar el valor para procesar o almacenar el comentario que la persona te deje en tu pagina, Cómo no se sabe bien que quieres hacer con la información, Investiga sobre Formularios o Forms y sus atributos en HTML,

Lo que puedes hacer es agregarle un action a tu form y un input que al momento de seleccionarlo, tome los datos y los procese.

```
  * <form action= "../pagina.html " target="_blank">
         <textarea name="comentarios" id="comentarios" cols="30" rows="10">
                Introduzca aquí sus comentarios
         </textarea>
      *   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

     </form>
```